# Function to separate and write dataset in chunks of n does not work. Tried array_slice and for-loop

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to separate and write chunks of n datapoints recursively from the first to n.

e.g. I want the first 20, then the next 20 (starting from the second point), and so on. From 1 to 20 (in a dataset of 40 points).

It seems to work at the beginning then the last chunks are offset by 1 point. I'm sure it has to be the most obvious error but I just can't wrap my head around it!!!

I've tried `array_slice()` and a `for()` loop. Both give me the same error.

```
function array_smas($series, $length){  # Uses array_slice()
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        echo "i = $i\n";
        $offset = $length - $i - 1;
        echo "offset = $offset\n";
        $series_n = array_slice($series, $offset, $length);
        file_put_contents(__DIR__."/file.txt", print_r($series_n, true), FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents(__DIR__."/file.txt", "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);   
    }
    return 0;
}



function array_smas_forloop($series, $length){  #   Uses for-loop
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        echo "i = $i\n";
        $series_n = array();
        for($c = 0; $c < $length; $c++){
            $series_n[] = $series[$c + $i];
        }
        file_put_contents(__DIR__."/file.txt", print_r($series_n, true), FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents(__DIR__."/file.txt", "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using a dataset of 40 points, the first and last arrays and $i outputs should be:

```
i = 0
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 13
    [13] => 14
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 16
    [16] => 17
    [17] => 18
    [18] => 19
    [19] => 20
)


...



i = 18
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 21
    [2] => 22
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 24
    [5] => 25
    [6] => 26
    [7] => 27
    [8] => 28
    [9] => 29
    [10] => 30
    [11] => 31
    [12] => 32
    [13] => 33
    [14] => 34
    [15] => 35
    [16] => 36
    [17] => 37
    [18] => 38
    [19] => 39
)


i = 19
Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] => 22
    [2] => 23
    [3] => 24
    [4] => 25
    [5] => 26
    [6] => 27
    [7] => 28
    [8] => 29
    [9] => 30
    [10] => 31
    [11] => 32
    [12] => 33
    [13] => 34
    [14] => 35
    [15] => 36
    [16] => 37
    [17] => 38
    [18] => 39
    [19] => 40
)
```

Comment: Arrays start at zero

Comment: Take a look at this function [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/array_chunk)

Comment: It would also be useful to see how you call these functions. please

Comment: Please show us some example data, desired output and what output you're currently getting.

Comment: Not sure where you get the 20 from is this `$length`?

Comment: @NigelRen yes.. thats the $length Im working with..

Comment: So can you show us what you think the last ouput for `$i` would be and the last array contents please

Comment: @RiggsFolly just edited the question

Comment: @MichalHynčica that function would just separate the dataset in chunks with the next one starting where the last (chunk) ended.. need the first chunk starting from point 1, then the second starting from point 2... etc..

Comment: Oh, i see. But then why in your example output i=19 starts with 21? i=20 should start with 21, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MichalHynčica thats what the question is about hehe.. i=19 —the 20th iteration—  should output the last 20 datapoints..

Comment: @NigelRen and the last line would be 39... need it to be 21 - 40

Comment: Sorry i'm kinda confused here. So the output in the question is desired output or the current wrong output? I thought it's desired output because you've written "outputs should be".

Comment: @MichalHynčica its the desired output the other user asked for..

Comment: What i don't understand is: If you started with $i = x and $a[0] = $x + 1, where it should become $i = x and $a[0] = $x + 2? Because in your desired output the first array is the first case and last two arrays are second case.

Comment: @MichalHynčica thats the whole point of the question.. how can I get that desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you can't have `$i = 19` and the first element as 21.  My logic is that if you look at the first loop where `$i` = 0, the first element is 1 - so 1 difference.  BUT when it's 19, you want the first element to be 21 - 2 higher than this number.

If in your `array_smas_forloop()` you change the limit of the loop to...

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++){
```

then you should get the desired output.

BUT, there is a lot of array creating and file opening and closing going on.  Another alternative is to create a 'window' on the array, remove the first item each time and add a new one to the end.  Also to open the file at the start of the function and close it at the end...

```
function array_smas_window($series, $length){  // Using for 'window'
    $output = fopen(__DIR__."/file.txt", "w");
    $window = array_slice($series, 0, $length);
    $i = 0;
    while(true) {
        fwrite($output, print_r($window, true)."\n\n");
        // If there are no more items, break the loop
        if ( !isset($series[$length+$i]) )  {
            break;
        }
        // Remove the first item
        array_shift($window);
        // Add a new one to the end
        $window[] = $series[$length+$i++];
     }
    fclose($output);
}
```

This should also work for any window size as it carries on till there are no more items to add on.

Comment: this does give me the right output, BUT I get 21 sets! I'm really confused here lol.. also I don't need to write the data to a file, an array with the right output is enough.  Why the 21 sets though? I understand it's looping 21 times from 0 -> 20..

Comment: Your first set starts with 1, and there are 19 more sets, so that means your 20th set will only start at 20.

Comment: Oh man this was too obvious I just couldn't grasp it.. Thank you